# Cannot fetch data (JSON) from URL - Java

Tags: java, https, httpurlconnection

I'm making a Java program and I want to fetch updates (JSON data) from URL of my website.
I used `HttpURLConnection` and `Pass SSL Certificate`.
I got this error while running:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
```

(`HTTPS` URL) 
I also try `HTTP` URL but the response code is `308`

Pass SSL Certificate code:

```
public static void setupIgnoreSSLCertificate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    final TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    }};

    final SSLContext disease = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    disease.init(null, trustManager, new SecureRandom());

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(disease.getSocketFactory());

    final HostnameVerifier aids = (s, sslSession) -> true;
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(aids);
}
```

Fetch code:

```
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        setupIgnoreSSLCertificate();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL(base + method);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(code != 200) {
            System.out.println("Error code: " + code);
        } else {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                text.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to pull a string from Http GET and aiming to convert into POJO?

Comment: @saadeez im trying to fetch the data (json) from the url base (i get with string then parse to json)

Comment: why dont you use Apache Commons Library for this? if you are un-aware then i can share its sample